# Lost my Desktop after upgrade to 17.10 no problem with nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, gnome-tweak-tool

I have followed the following posts
[How do I get my folders back on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199044/how-do-i-get-my-folders-back-on-my-desktop) and 
[Files and folders in the Desktop disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327669/files-and-folders-in-the-desktop-disappeared). Also tried enabling desktop icons through dconf-editor and Tweak tool but no success.
The file manager is fairly stable. I can access my desktop through it.
How can I track what is exactly is wrong with my os configuration or find out what is missing?

Comment: That is a good question. I went to Gnome and added them to Desktop and they appeared on Unity but this cannot be the solution.

Comment: @EODCraft Staff:

Comment: @EODCraft Staff: I have uninstalled unity after upgrade, I'll try reinstalling the same, however I want use new ubuntu features as well.